# ColdFusion - form post issues on safari even on a most basic test form: no data seem to go through

Tags: coldfusion, safari

While converting a bunch of IE-only stuff to be available for use on other browsers as well, I ran into some weird issue on Safari browser.
In order to try to isolate the issue, I wrote a VERY basic test page, but I still can't get what's causing the problem.

The very basic test form I'm experimenting with looks like this:

```
<form name="testForm" action="test2.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="testField" value="testValue">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="go">
</form>
```

I guess that should be simple enough, right?

Now to what's happening: no matter what I try, it seems that the "test2.cfm" page to which the form is submitted does not receive anything at all.

- If I try to use the "testField" variable in it, I get a CF error 'cause it's undefined, as if it hasn't been submitted or it's misspelled (needless to say I triple-checked the spelling)
- If I try to loop on all the data received from the form, I get nothing at all, as if the form did not contain a single thing.

All of the above is happening only on Safari browser, whereas it's working fine as it should on IE, Opera, Firefox, Chrome.

- I also tried to script-submit the form instead of using a submit-type button, but nothing changed (not that I was really expecting it to: I tried it out of desperation more than anything else)
- I tried with both normal form and cfform, and the result is still the same.

I know I'm most probably being blind/dumb/whatever and my brain feels likely already on vacation 'cause it's Xmas time, but I really don't get what's going on here... any ideas anyone to help little-old-noob-me out?

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Right, forgot to mention it. Safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7), ColdFusion 8

Comment: Is there any more HTML wrapping that form, or is that the whole page?

Comment: just the html and body tags, nothing else

Comment: What do you get if you `<cfdump var="#form#" />` on test2.cfm?

Comment: Can you paste the code for the entire form page and its name, and for the entire action page, test2.cfm?

Comment: @s992 - I get a struct[empty], which I guess is why if I look on the received data I get nothing

Comment: @Vos - It is sending you to test2.cfm when you submit the form, correct? Is there an Application.cfm/cfc that could be altering the form struct?

Comment: @BarryJordan - test1.cfm:  <html>
<body>
<form name="testForm" action="test2.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="testField" value="testValue">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="go">
</form>
</body>
</html>


test2.cfm:

<html>
<body>
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="theField">
<cfoutput>
 #theField# = #form[theField]#<br>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @s992 yes it's sending me to test2.cfm, and nope the form struct should not be altered by anything (and it works normally on every other browser)

Comment: I just tried it on Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS X Lion, using CF9 developer edition, and it worked fine. (Copying and pasting your full source for both files, above).

Comment: @JakeFeasel uhm... I guess this could mean it can somehow be either CF8 or Safari for Win7 fault?

Comment: Also working fine on Safari 5.1.2 on Windows 7 using CF9 developer edition.

Comment: @s992 mmh.... this could narrow it down to CF8... gonna try on Safari on Win7 + CF8 in a couple mins (found a collegue with a mac)

Comment: Ok, first of all my apologies for a wrong info: it's CF7 and not CF8. Now to the latest tests: CF7 + Safari 5.0.2 on MAC -> ok. CF7 + Safari Mobile on an iPhone4 -> ok. I'm really running out of ideas here... could it be some sort of incompatibility between CF7 and Safari for Win, maybe solved in later versions of CF?

Comment: Do you have the problem if you load up a static HTML version of your form in Safari (i.e. file:/// url)?

Comment: I'll echo the earlier comment about an Application.cfm file maybe being involved. Please check for the existence of an Application.cfm in the same directory, or ANY higher directory. If you see one, look in there and see if any code is clearing the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on 'Safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7)' and all are working fine. I am able to access the 'Form.testField' variable in my action page(test2.cfm). Review the code of your action page, remove the browser cache and try again.